# UE4 C++ Rotation Speed

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I want to make a solar system model in Unreal Engine 4. I am a complete novice and this will be my second ever project. I was wandering how I could set the rotation path of a 'planet' and change its speed. For example the rotation of Jupiter around the sun would be slower than the roation speed of Earth around the sun.

Thank you

Comment: Hello!  Welcome to stack overflow.  Please [read about how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I think this link will provide the answer you are looking for [https://forums.unrealengine.com/community/work-in-progress/9147-solar-system-simulator-wip](https://forums.unrealengine.com/community/work-in-progress/9147-solar-system-simulator-wip)

Answer (score 0):

You could model your planets with them on a root a certain distance away from the sun, then make a timeline that has a track from 0-360 degrees over a set amount of time (revolution time for example).

Parent your planets to the sun,then set relative Rotation of your planets root with the float value that your timeline returns.

Hope this helped.